# Trouble escaping a string: Powershell -> Bash -> More Bash

Tags: bash, powershell, escaping, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on Powershell 7 and WSL/bash.

Based on another answer on this site, I've created my own knock-off version of `watch` that is capable of displaying more colors. And so far it's worked ok. It looks like this:

```
while sleep 1; do
   x="$("$@" 2>&1)"
   clear
   echo "$x"
done
```

I am trying to pass in the following command `my_watch` to have it repeat:

```
task rc.defaultwidth=$(tput cols)
```

Which in Powershell/WSL looks something like this:

```
wsl ~/my_watch 'task rc.defaultwidth=$(tput cols)'
```

The problem is that the `$(tput cols)` is being evaluated too early, I think right before `my_watch` is invoked. So the result of the calculation is being passed to `my_watch`, which means the width is being set up front and then doesn't change during the watch loop.

I want every cycle of `my_watch` for the number of columns to be recalculated so that it is adaptable to window resizing.

But I can't figure out how to escape the `tput cols` part so that it waits until inside the `my_watch` loop to execute.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `"$@"` only allows passing fixed arguments, not an expression to compute arguments (like `$(tput cols)`). To pass an expression, you'd have to do something like pass it as a single-quoted string, and then use `eval` to parse it. Unfortunately, while this approach would be more powerful, it's also even harder to get right and adds lots of ways to get bizarre unexpected results.

Comment: I guess one solution would be to hardcode the passed in value and turn it from a generic watch script into a non generic display_task script.